# Fort Peck historic topographic maps

Tags: data-request, usa, historical

I am looking for historic [topographic maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_map) of the Missouri River before the [Fort Peck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Peck,_Montana) Reservoir/Dam was built in 1940 (in the area of the Fort Peck Reservoir). I have searched National Map Viewer but they only have a small portion of the area. If anyone has scans of these topos or knows where I could look or find them I’d be grateful!

Alternatively if anyone had bathymetry data for Fort Peck Reservoir, that would be second best!

Answer (score 1):

Did the National map lead you to the USGS Historical Topographic Map Collection?

I imagine this would be the best source -
https://www.usgs.gov/programs/national-geospatial-program/historical-topographic-maps-preserving-past

And a viewer app here
https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/topoexplorer/index.html

but if this was the source where you only found partial coverage for your area, you may want to try (if you haven't already) putting a call out on Twitter under the #GISChat tag or maybe check the Library of Congress of map archives?